# grep matching asterisk in beginning of string

Tags: unix, grep

Simple stuff I think but I've been stuck what is the regex to match the lines that have only one asterisks in the beginning of the string instead of ones with 1-4 in the front? grep '^*' matches everything

Comment: Do you want to accept lines that contain an asterisk somewhere besides the start? For example, should the line `* Search for *.h files` be considered a match?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
grep '^[*][^*]'
```

To break it down,

```
^    <-- Beginning of the line
[*]  <-- Exactly one instance of the character *
[^*] <-- Exactly one instance of a character that is NOT *
```

**Edit**

As Amadan points out in his comment, this will miss any lines containing only a single `*` and nothing else, because the `[^*]` portion goes unmatched in this case.  If you want to account for "empty" lines starting with a single `*`, then you could change it to

```
grep '^[*]\([^*]\|$\)'
```

Which breaks down as

```
^         <-- Beginning of the line
[*]       <-- Exactly one instance of the character *
\(X\|Y\)  <-- Either expression X  OR  expression Y

    [^*]  <-- Exactly one instance of a character that is NOT *
                 -- OR --
    $     <-- The end of the line
```

Comment: I'd go with `^[*][^*]*$` to ensure lines with only one asterisk and no next character match too.

Comment: There we go! thanks man. Dare to explain it if you have the time? Just trying to wrap my head around this stuff

Comment: Sure, does my edit explain it? Or do you still have questions?

Comment: @Amadan Your regex will not match any lines that contain a `*` within the line.  I think that `^[*][^*]*.*$` would do the trick.  However, since grep is already processing one line at a time, you don't really need the `$`. For example `^[*][^*]*` would do the same thing (when used with grep)

Comment: Yeah so the first set shows what not to after matching and the second set is what you need to match?

Comment: @nispio: I understood it can only have one asterisk, and it should be at the beginning of the line. If the desired interpretation was at the beginning of the line a single asterisk, with possibility of more later, then I'd do `^[*]\([^*]\|$\)` (star followed by either non-star or end of line). Your pattern `^[*][^*]*` would not do the same thing, since it would trivially match the line `**` (with zero repetitions of non-star).

Comment: @Amadan: Great point. Thanks!  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: the above regex would match this pattern also ' *content *'

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
grep ^\* [^ *] *$
```

`^` begining of the line

`$` end of the line

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  The extra spaces mess everything up.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this,

Create a file with following content

```
cat a.txt

*abc
**def
***gh
*****
```

**grep '^*[^*]' a.txt**

```
Ans : *abc
```

You can try this in your unix server